# Parent and child div with form

Tags: css, overflow

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/bUPWS/1/ but #div2 overflows #div1. How to bring the overflowed inputs next to the other ones?

```
    <div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <form>
            <input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/><input/><br/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

#div1 {
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: you should also add you your code in you question. i appreciate that you showed the example but sometimes access to website is limited and many people cannot understand your problem

Comment: seeing your code i can say you are using `<br />` tag so there is no possible way to bring your inputs next to each other. just remove each `<br/>` all your inputs will align properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seeing your code i can say you are using `<br />` tag so there is no possible way to bring your inputs next to each other. just remove each `<br/>` all your inputs will align properly.

additionally you can use `min-height` for your parent div `div1`

```
#div1 {
    width:400px;
    min-height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#div2 input {display:inline; }
```

if your inputs increases more than the limit of `100px height` your parent div will adjust the height with respect to the inputs inside your `div2` block

**EDIT:** However to explain my comment below i have updated your fiddle example you can check how we can achieve it using `<ul> <li></li></ul>` tags

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/A3BwB/6/)

Code if here!

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <form>
            <ul>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
           </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
                <li><input/></li>
            </ul>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
    width:800px;
    min-height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
*{padding:0; margin:0}
#div2 ul{float:left; padding-left:10px; }
```

Comment: OK but if width is 800px it doesn't work.I mean that I want the inputs to go to the end of the #div1 and then the other to go next to the first. I can do it with two divs and float but I'm wondering if they're really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you looking for but you can set overflow:auto for div 1 and set float:left, for inputs.  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUPWS/28/

Answer (score 0):

Try using fieldset instad of div.
see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp